# How to have a window size that adapts to its content size and vice versa?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, window-resize, stretch

This is quite a conundrum to me because I have quite a mess about it.
So let's imagine having a window with **SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"**

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" >
    
    <ListBox Name="lbxInfo" Margin="10" FontSize="30" Grid.Row="0"/>
</Window>
```

so the window has to adapt to its content. Easy peasy.

But here comes the hard part. The content is variable and adapts stretches the window size.
So the biggest string well be correctly stretched.

```
lbxInfo.Items.Add(new TextBox() { Text="AAA", Background = Brushes.Aqua, HorizontalContentAlignment= HorizontalAlignment.Stretch  });
lbxInfo.Items.Add(new TextBox() { Text = "BBB BBB", Background = Brushes.LavenderBlush, HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch });
lbxInfo.Items.Add(new TextBox() { Text = "CCC CCC CCC", Background = Brushes.Lime, HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch });
```

Here's the result:

[image]

instead I wish it was this one:

[image]

so I wish each element to stretch (resize/adjust) to the largest of them.

The only way to achieve I can think this is to have a first loop on the elements calculate the biggest, then set the size of the window upon the result.

Is there any efficient way to do it?

*** ADD ***

Following Clemens solution I have done this in code behind and that works wonder!

```
var lbxInfo = new ListBox() { FontSize= 30 };
wndMain.Content = lbxInfo ;
lbxInfo.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = "AAA", Background = Brushes.Aqua });
lbxInfo.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = "BBB BBB", Background = Brushes.LavenderBlush });
lbxInfo.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = "CCC CCC CCC", Background = Brushes.Lime });
```

and the result is magnificient!

[image]

Comment: You should not be adding TextBoxes to the Items collection. Instead, pass a collection of data items with a string property to the ItemsSource and declare the TextBox in the ItemTemplate. Then set the HorizontalAlignment of the ListBoxItems to Stretch in an ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: But I need them in different colours

Comment: Then add a color property to the data item class and bind to it in the ItemTemplate, as usual. You are not doing this since yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ListBox with `HorizontalContentAlignment` of its ListBoxItems set to `Stretch`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="30">
                <TextBox.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
                </TextBox.Background>
            </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Please see my ADD and tell me if that seems OK. I forgot to tell that I have to do it in code behind. Actually it seems very simple. Have I forgotten something? I have never used binding

Comment: Seems ok. However, "*I have to do it in code behind*" is usually wrong. You would create the data items in code behind, but still declare the UI in XAML. "*I have never used binding*" sounds totally odd for someone who works with WPF since years.